# Split different path structures generic - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

in the beginning I had a path with always the same structure: `projectnumber/moduleXY/src/test.py` and I always splitted module like:

```
splitted_path = project_path.split(os.sep) 
module = splitted_path[1]
```

Now I have to do it generic cause I don't know the dimension of my path. And some of my paths don't have any module so I habe to take another spitted part for example

For example:

```
projectnumber/ID/TestCASE/doc/documentation.txt--> save TestCase 
projectnumber/module1/spec/req.rst-> save module1
newProjectname/ID/Product/doc/documentation.txt-> save Product
```

I really dont know how to do it cause I can't use `splitted_path[1]` anymore, cause I dont know if the module, component or Product is in the `[1]` palce of the array.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: What is the structure of `ID` ? could you share some examples ?

Comment: Are the patterns in your example exhaustive? As in, are those the only patterns that appear in your paths? In the examples you've shown - the module name is either at `[1]` or `[2]` - depending on the existence of `ID`, if you can tell us what this `ID` looks like - that might be able to help in finding a logical identification pattern.

Comment: @azro ID was just example I don't event know the structure of the future projects :/ so I have to save at least one modulename or componentname which makes sense. Like in the examples

Comment: @Chase No they are just examples what the paths can look like. Its really hard for me to do it generic without knowing the dimension of the path

Comment: if you don't know in which place will be module then code also will not know. You have to figure out how **YOU** recognize module in path - if not by position then maybe by next/previous element (ie. first element after ID) or maybe by some words in name (dictionary with words). But if this doesn't help and you don't know future structure then you can't create solution. You simply ask for magic (and even artificial intelligence may not help).

Comment: or maybe you should check what files you have in folder to recognize project. For example project from github will have folder `.git`. And Django project should have file `manager.py`. And as I remeber project created by `PyCharm` may have file/folder `.idea`

Comment: @furas I have asked for more details about the paths. Maybe I will get some infomation. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

You can also index from right to left, e.g.:

```
project_path = "projectnumber/ID/TestCASE/doc/documentation.txt"
splitted = project_path.split(os.sep) 
module = splitted[-3]
```

which in this case would be equivalent to:

```
module = splitted[2]
```

Alternatively you could also use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("projectnumber/ID/TestCASE/doc/documentation.txt")

module_path = path.parent.parent.name

# path.parent -> Path("projectnumber/ID/TestCASE/doc")
# path.parent.parent -> Path("projectnumber/ID/TestCASE")
# path.parent.parent.name -> "TestCASE"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but is it not so risky to wirte splitted [-3], if you don't know the path structure? and the variable that will be safed should not be something like src  or doc, it must be somthing unique cause with this I will create/open a file with this name.  What if the path looks like this project_name/modulexy/tests/doc/doc.txt and I want modulexy ? Just n example cause I really have to do it generic but idk how

Comment: I have asked for more details about the paths.